# How to comment out a block of code that already has multiple line comments?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do something like this in Javascript?

```
/*
    code
    /* Multiple
    line
    comment */
    more code
*/
```

When I test, I often need to comment out large chunks of code that already have multiline comments.

Comment: Just add line comments instead of block comments. Nested block comments are still commented that way.

Comment: A good IDE can help here - for instance Visual Studio allows for selecting a block of text, and saying comment/uncomment, where it inserts/removes line comments as appropriate

Comment: Please look into this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201388/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-nested-comments

Comment: I guess you should use line comment. Long block comments will create confusion

Comment: Which IDE or editor are you using?

Comment: @lewis4u I'm using Sublime text editor

Comment: In sublime text you can go to Preferences/Key Bindings and add these lines in right window if they are not there....[
 { "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
 { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
] then you can use Ctrl+7 to comment or Ctrl+Shift+7 to uncomment the selected code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your IDE have find and replace option.

Add `/*` at starting
and `*/` at ending

Within the code block

Replace `*/` with `*//*`

**then to if you want to remove the comments you made** :

Remove `/*` at starting, Remove `*/` at ending

Within the code block

Replace `*//*` with `*/`

Comment: Well no, this is cumbersome and what if you have ```selector.trim().replace(/^>\s*/, "");``` anyway ? Block comment won't work in this case . Use if(false){ } or function codeTodisable(){} to disable lines of code

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer, per-se.  But the fact that block comments can't also block nested comments is a horrifically lame situation to begin with.  The answer is to fix JS.

The obvious rule:  ****EVERYTHING**** between the comment tags is to be treated as a comment.  Period.  To re-interpret commented text as functional in any way is just not sane.  Commented text should not have any functional symbology.... it should not be getting parsed at all.... no excuses.  Commented text should be absolutely dead.  Non-funcitonal.

Answer (score 1):

In VS studio I was able to highlight the lines of code and use 'ctrl + /' and it toggles the lines of code to either be commented out or back in. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use block editing feature in text editor. For example, in notepad++, you hold alt key to select the first position of each line, then type "//". you will find the "//" will appear in every line that you have selected.

It shouldn't cost your more than 10secs

Comment: If I was to do this on my code base it'd take me several hours not 10 secs

Answer (score 0):

Alright, comments are for comments don't try to disable large chunks of code with it.

Since we don't have macro like in C, instead use tricks like this:

```
if(false){ // Disable code
    ...
}
```

```
function disabledCode(){
    ...
};

// re-enable code: 
disabledCode();
```